Flutter universal_io/io 'Stream has already been listened to.'
for some reason, I suddenly get the Stream has already been listened to. error with the following code when it runs to .join() for the stream. I am using universal_io/io for http call.
final url = Uri.https(host, path, query);

      final request = await httpClient.postUrl(url);

      await _setHeaders(
        request: request,
        requireToken: requireToken,
        token: token,
        headers: headers,
      );

      request.write(json.encode(body));

      final response =
          await request.close().timeout(Duration(seconds: timeout));

      print(response);
      print(response.statusCode);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final responseBody = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
        final responseJson = jsonDecode(responseBody);
      }

However, if I put a get request side by side, the get request works fine
final url = Uri.https(host, path, toValidQuery(query));

      final request = await httpClient.getUrl(url);

      await _setHeaders(
          request: request,
          requireToken: requireToken,
          token: token,
          headers: headers);

      final response =
          await request.close().timeout(Duration(seconds: timeout));

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final responseBody = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
        return Result.success(payload: responseBody);
      }

Here is how they put together
    final responseResult1 = await httpClientService.get(
      host: environmentVariableService.getServerUrl(),
      path: '/users',
      requireToken: false,
    );

    final responseResult2 = await httpClientService.post(
        host: environmentVariableService.getServerUrl(),
        path: '/users',
        body: request,
        requireToken: false);


This line print(response) will have likely consumed the stream before you get to trying to read it. Try removing it.
